# Why I can't see real request headers here

Tags: google-chrome, http, caching, http-headers, google-chrome-devtools

[image]

Look at Request headers it says `Provisional headers are shown`, I read somewhere on SO   "The message is there because the request to retrieve that resource was never made"

I am getting 304 Response from the server that mean surely a request has been send to server ,

So why i can't see real request headers ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Google server was sending an incorrect response code back. It should send `304 Not Modified` not `304`. I got the correct response without that warning message using the jQuery CDN.

After a while, I noticed that the Google server started sending the correct response back and the message disappeared, and then it returned again. It is a peculiar issue but it doesn't seem to prevent anything from working.